# Moving Scroller in a Command

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a MainView that contains a scrollViewer, from its ViewModel I have a command to move the page Up or Down (I need to accomplish this using the scroller because I only have one long page), by doing something like this `Scroller.PageUP();` But my problem is that how can I access the scroller or how to fire an event to code behind to do it there, because in the MainCommad Class I only have access to my ViewModel.

Comment: This shouldn't be the responsibility of the ViewModel. If you still want to do it get the basic control template of scroll viewer create an attached properties for UpCommand and DownCommand and bind to those. On invoke call ScrollBar.LineUpCommand and ScrollBar.LineDownCommand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EventToCommand`, it's available in the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I raised an `event Action` called  `ScrollUp();` and in my code behind of the `xaml` I did this

```
MyViewModel.ScrollUp += new Action(On_ScrollUp); 
void On_ScrollUp()
        {
            Scroller.PageUp(); //Scroller is my ScrollViewer
        }
```

If there's a better approach please feel free to post a solution.